# Guice Assisted Inject with multiple implementations of interface

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an interface A with multiple implementations say B, C and D.
I am using guice assisted inject to create these classes. Classes B and C use the same assister parameters(say b, c) in constructor while D has one different parameter(say d).
The way I implementing this is have a factory AFactory with 2 methods:
create(int b, int c) and createD(int d)
In my module, I have created a PrivateModule to bind the concrete class to factory.

The code looks like this:

```
public static PrivateModule getAFactoryModule(final String factoryBindingKey,final Class<? extends A> targetClassToCreate) {
    return new PrivateModule() {

        @Override
        public void configure() {
            install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(
                    A.class, targetClassToCreate).build(
                    AFactory.class));

            bind(AFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(factoryBindingKey)).to(
                    Key.get(AFactory.class));
            expose(Key.get(AFactory.class, Names.named(factoryBindingKey)));
        }
    };
}
```

I call PrivateModule like this:

```
install(getAFactoryModule("B", B.class));
install(getAFactoryModule("C", C.class));
install(getAFactoryModule("D", D.class));
```

But, this gives an error saying:

```
com.guice.test.B has @AssistedInject constructors but none of them match the parameters in method com.guice.test.AFactory.createD(). Unable to create assisted inject

com.guice.test.C has @AssistedInject constructors but none of them match the parameters in method com.guice.test.AFactory.createD(). Unable to create assisted inject

com.guice.test.D has @AssistedInject constructors but none of them match the parameters in method com.guice.test.AFactory.create(). Unable to create assisted inject
```

It seems Guice is trying to use different create methods than what is expected. Any idea how this can be resolved? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are doing something unsafe—leaving some of your factory methods unresolved—and Guice is confused. Basically, FactoryModuleBuilder is generating the following code:

```
@Named("B") public class GeneratedBClass implements AFactory {
  A create(int b, int c) { return new B(...); }
  A create(int d) { /* no implementation! */ }
}
@Named("C") public class GeneratedBClass implements AFactory {
  A create(int b, int c) { return new C(...); }
  A create(int d) { /* no implementation! */ }
}
@Named("D") public class GeneratedBClass implements AFactory {
  A create(int b, int c) { /* no implementation! */ }
  A create(int d) { return new D(...); }
}
```

Those three missing implementations are the reason Guice is complaining: Guice can't find a good implementation for those, and figures that you'll want them wired up. Beyond Guice, though, you've got a very dangerous API designed: Depending on your configuration, one of your methods will work, and one cannot work—which is more dangerous than DI was designed for.

I would either switch your configuration to only switch "B" and "C", and have both of those expose a "D":

```
public interface AFactory {
  @Named("BorC") A create(int B, int C);
  @Named("D") A create(int D);
}

install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(A.class, Names.named("BorC"), targetClassToCreate)
    .implement(D.class, Names.named("D"), D.class)
    .build(AFactory.class));
```

...or, because you should know at compile time whether you're going to call the two-argument or one-argument constructor, just switch D to its own factory:

```
public interface DFactory {
  D create(int D);
}

// If DFactory creates an A, you need implement(). Otherwise, this works.
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(DFactory.class));
```